# I can't display the correct message in the chat app - React

Tags: reactjs, state, chat

I'm currently developing a chat app using React and I'm having a little problem with it. When you type something in the textarea but don't send it and go to chat with the other customer -  the text that was entered for the first chat remains in the field

I would be grateful if you could help me :)

Answer (score 0):

You specified `setMessage` in dependencies for the `useCallback` hook, try to set `message`, it should looks like this:

```js
const changeMessage = useCallback(
    (event) => {
      setMessage(event.target.value);
    },
    [message, previousMessage],
  );
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that too but no change :/

Answer (score 0):

You need run setMessage("") when you are changing chat to other customer.